# Test case for the function which is calling Async function with mocha and chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, bdd, chai

I have function which return promise. here is the code of function.

```
function  firstFunction () {
   return new Promise (function (resolve , return) {
          callApi(function(data, error){
                     if (data)  resolve (data)
                     else if (error) reject (error)  
          })
   })
}
```

as you can see it is calling some api and on result its returning data.

I have another function  which call this function

```
function  secondFunction () {
  firstFunction ().then(function (data , error) {
          return data
  })
}
```

Now I want to write test case for the **secondfunction** . but not able to do this. I put logger also in the functions but seems not working, here is my test case

```
   describe.only ("network_test" , function () {
      it ("test 01", function (done){

        secondFunction (function (data) {
           console.log(data);
           done()
         })
       })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

To test promises you should return the promise in the mocha test and not use `done`.

Your test should be something like:

```
describe.only('network_test', function () {
    it('test 01', function () {
       return secondFunction(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
       });
    });
});
```

---

**Update:**
Regarding your comment: check your error handlers, in `firstFunction` `reject` is `undefinded`. in `secondFunction` an error will make the promise to never resolve.

Comment: not working . its keep saying

 Error: timeout of 15000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

test case for firstFunction is working thogh